# Network drops shortly after restart. Disable/Enable fixes until next restart

Tags: windows-7, networking, device-manager

My network drops out shortly after restarting. Disabling/enabling the adapter in Device Manager brings the network connection back up until the next restart. I have disabled the on-board LAN and installed a new NIC but the problem persists. After restarting, I've noticed that the network is up for a few seconds (as I can load a web page) but drops out within a few seconds. Interestingly, this is one of two identical computers that I built with matching hardware and software. The clone doesn't suffer this problem.

I would love to find a solution for this. Alternatively, I would settle for a batch file that would disable/enable the NIC.

Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: Not a solution, but might be useful: [Is it possible to toggle disabled/enabled devices from Command Line, simlar to Device Manager?](http://superuser.com/q/788385/289138)

Comment: What's the [hardware ID](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-Hardware-ID) of the network card? What's the current driver version you're using? Do you get the same issue if you [start Windows in Safe Mode with Networking](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-computer-safe-mode#start-computer-safe-mode=windows-7) or [perform a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us)? Did you check the [event viewer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7) for further details?