# Shortcut to enable/disable a device in Windows

Tags: windows, device-manager

I need to disable/enable a device (a steering wheel) in Windows with a shortcut or a automated script instead of going to Device Manager and, if possible, avoiding the restart when I enable it.

I found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1165637/one-gesture-solution-to-disable-enable-a-device-in-device-manager-without-a-thi) which identified my question and I even tried [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1166546/880618) shortcut path but it didn't work (it's throwing an error and automatically closes `cmd`).

I tried this with no success:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName \"Logitech MOMO Racing USB\" | Disable-PnpDevice -confirm:$false; Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName \"Logitech MOMO Racing USB\" | Enable-PnpDevice -confirm:$false"
```

The reason being is because most older games tend to detect my steering wheel as some kind of gamepad and it causes weird behavior in-game.

What can I do to achieve this?

---

<sub>**Note**: I know it's way easier to unplug and plug again but the cables are not so accesible and I have the cables all wrapped and organized, that's why I'm looking for a software solution.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the Microsoft utility of
[Windows Device Console (Devcon.exe)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon)
to enable and disable drivers, and may create icons for these commands on the
desktop.

This utility is part of the Windows Driver Kit, Visual Studio, or the
Windows SDK for desktop apps.
To avoid installing these heavy products, see the post
[Quick Method to install DevCon.exe?](https://superuser.com/questions/1002950/quick-method-to-install-devcon-exe)

To see an example of using Devcon, see the post
[Running the devcon.exe properly (enabling/disabling the device from command line in Windows 10)](https://superuser.com/questions/1272966/running-the-devcon-exe-properly-enabling-disabling-the-device-from-command-line)
and also
[ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/devcon.html).